# Is XML parsing blocked on amazon product API requests?

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services

I am trying to parse/recieve the XML from the amazon product API. When sending a api request to amazon I can successfully receive a url containing the XML data for the product(s). When I try to use the `simplexml_load_file()` function in php I get a connection refused. 
Is this amazon blocking the use of this sort of request, or is it more likely a problem on my end? (I am only testing in XAMPP)

Comment: It's more likely an issue on your end. Perhaps your web server is not configured to allow outgoing web requests?

Comment: if you're having trouble with simple_xml, you can use file_get_contents instead and parse it that way.